SharePoint Insert Item into List throws 400 when payload contains Scandic Character in Rest API
I have a share point list and when i  try to create Item with Rest API call it throws 400 bad request error. here is my payload

{
 "__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.TestListItem"},
 "FIRST_x0020_NAME":"YÄSIR ALI"
} 

Request Headers
 headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8',
      accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
      Host: '****.sharepoint.com',
      'Content-Length': body.length
    }

i am using axios.post
I have tried changing content-type e.g ('content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8') event setting
accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8'

'content-transfer-encoding': 'binary',


The issue is resolved, here is my final code snippet which worked
firstly, I converted my payload to byte Buffer
const bytePayload = Buffer.from(payload, 'utf-8');
secondly, I removed  'Content-Length': body.length and charset=utf-8 from headers
